# PHP.INI values changing across different files in the same application

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I'm trying to override some php.ini variables for my application, as the array elements were getting truncated when posting them to another PHP program through an AJAX call. The number of elements in the array could be anywhere between 5000 to 10000, and the limit imposed by the hosting is 1000.

It looked to me that overriding "max_input_vars" and "post_max_size" would be the right way to go about this issue. And, I initially tried overriding these values in .htaccess file, but the program chose to bypass the htaccess values. Next, I created a custom php.ini file and placed it in the root folder, and not just the application folder, of the hosting (as suggested by their technical support). I could see the override values in one of the application programs, however, it's when I make an internal AJAX call, strange results are observed! Please see the attached snapshot:

[image: max_input_vars issue]

max_input_vars (obtained using ini_get() function) in the foreground PHP program can be seen to have the value as '9999999'. However, despite this, the program that receives the AJAX request reverts the max_input_vars to the default server configuration!!

Just for a note, the directory structure is as follows:

```
    /public_html
    - php.ini
    / application_root
        - first_program.php
        /sub-folder
            - second_program.php
```

[image: max_input_vars]
Any suggestions please? What causes the second program to revert the override? There's no code in there that would do that... moreover, any attempts to set max_input_vars from ini_set() are simply ignored by the programs - at least under this host. How can I make sure that all the programs under the application exhibit a uniform behavior towards php.ini values?

Many Thanks for your help and inputs!

Comment: Does the second program root point same as the first one? And have you tried setting the values (ini_set) right from the program index.php?

Comment: @JA, well yeah.. they both point to the same root. In fact, the second program resides within a subfolder of the application and because php.ini resides further up in the first level of the hosting directory, I was hoping the php.ini values would apply to all the applications under this hosting. With regards to setting the value in index.php, well, I've tried that, but to no avail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changeability of both max_input_vars and post_max_size [is PHP_INI_PERDIR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) which means they [can be set in](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf but not using ini_set().

So, create a .htaccess file in your application_root with

> php_value max_input_vars 12345

Now in that directory create a test file that will reflect the value of max_input_vars, and check it by accessing it.  For example:

```
<?php
error_log(var_export(ini_get('max_input_vars')));
?>
```

You mind letting us know if the value is not the one defined in the .htaccess?

Comment: Hi @Ronen Botzer,
Many Thanks for your reply! And my apologies for the delayed response. It was really useful to know about the "changeability" attribute and that link - which confirms why the override values from code - ini_set() - didn't work. Had tried .htaccess file, but that was ignored too. 

In the snapshot above - an AJAX call to another module in the application subfolder - it was found that the values were not same, with the php.ini being in base folder of the hosting. The calling program (within app folder) picked up the custom php.ini value, but the program in sub folder didn't!

Comment: Following your suggestion, I placed the php.ini in the application folder too. However, that didn't change the result yet! I don't know if this was a fluke or something, but when I placed the exact same php.ini in the application subfolder too, the receiving program picked the settings well :)


`    /public_html
        / application_root
     - php.ini
            - first_program.php
            /sub-folder
                - (same) php.ini (yes, again!)
                - second_program.php`

Comment: Am sorry, despite trying several times I was unable to present the structure properly.. Hope the description makes sense though? Many Thanks!

Comment: Hey Dhruv, sorry about the delay.  I just got back from vacation, and as much as I love wrestling with PHP's quirks... :)  Not sure yet how to get around it.  Let me look into it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks @Ronen Botzer... Please, do feel free to ask if you want me to provide any additional details with regards to the original problem or the fix. I wasn't experimenting a lot with it right now because an additional php.ini file (in the sub folder) doesn't hurt. However, if you'd like any tests to be performed with a different setup, etc.. please do not hesitate to advise. Thank you again.

Comment: Do you mind showing the output of the following? "php -i| grep ini".  I want to see what the Loaded Configuration File is, and the Configuration File Path, as well as the possible Additional .ini files parsed.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ronen, Hope you're well. I really wouldn't mind providing you with that dump, however it is a shared hosting and we don't have a shell access for it. The problem was virtually non existent on the local machine (and it is Windows anyway), so the dump from here would be irrelevant too.. 

Any other way I could get that information for you? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, Dhruv, I've been busy getting the new PHP client for Aerospike DB out.  And honestly, I'm stumped!